# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb while doing bs

Tags: python, xml, file, encoding, beautifulsoup

I save the xml page locally from an API of Merriam-Webster, let me give you the url:
http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/apple?key=bf534d02-bf4e-49bc-b43f-37f68a0bf4fd

That was an example.
I urlretrieve it from the url and save it as a xml file.

Now I want to open it but a `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs.

I did :

```
page = open('test.xml')
bs = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Then the following error happens:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcb
```

I tried to make the url `u'test.xml'` it didn't work.

> > > sys.getdefaultencoding()
> > >          'utf-8'

The encoding configuration is already utf-8, which doesn't solve the problem, thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding as utf-8 which is what the data is encoded as, the filename has nothing to do with what is inside so prefixing with u to make a unicode string is not going to help:

```
import io
with io.open('test.xml', encoding="utf-8") as page:
      bs = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use pickle module, when I use that, it says that I run out of  inpuy

Comment: @AlexZhang, how were you using pickle?

Comment: Wait a minute, I am trying something...I will explain soon

Comment: So this is what I did with pickle:

   htmlFile = urlopen(theUrl).read().decode('utf-8')
   with open(filePath, 'wb') as file:
      pickle.dump(htmlFile, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

And I think that maybe it is because I right the argument as wb so that it is stored as btyes, anyway next is:

   with open(filePath,'rb') as file:
      print(filePath,':',pickle.load(file))
      return pickle.load(file)
So when I try to load it it say that kind of problem. And no matter what I try about opening it decode it into utf-8 it won't work, because the same error happens when read()

Comment: Why are you dumping the html using pickle?

Comment: Actually I tried everything I know, I tried just open and write, I tried urlretrieve, and pickle was my only hope, they all malfunction... Seems like that's something about python3? As aforementioned, I use python 3.4.4. I tried your method, the same error occurs, but thanks. If you know what is going on now please help

Comment: Add the full error traceback

Comment: Thank you so much I just solved it! I just need to simply open the file using f = open(filename, 'rb'), and BeautifulSoup(f), then it can work.